# Can a pseudo element content be used to call an ID or a class?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Let's say I have an html element with an ID and another `<div>` element with a pseudo class like :before. Can I call the first element to the second one with the content attribute of a ":before" so that in the end there would be multiple cases of the first element on the page?  **Is this possible with just the CSS pseudo element?**

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
        <p id="boo">Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div id="baa"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#baa:after 
{content: "#boo";}
```

**Result on the page**

```
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: using content: attr(x); [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)? is this what you want?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I would like to replicate existing content (such as text) multiple times via pseudo element (by having a pseudo element call an existing id via content), but I don't know if it's even possible.

The situation that brought this up was when thinking about a <table> element on mobile. The <th> element had to be hidden, but I wondered if the individual headings could be recalled to other parts of the page using only CSS.

Comment: if you need to hide/show for mobile/desktop why don't you use media queries and css styles like display none. What you are asking cannot be done with only css. As the coment above says the only thing you could use is the `attr` inside the pseudo element

Comment: @MihaiT "why don't you use media queries and css styles like display none." That's actually what I'm doing currently, and I was just wondering if you could use a pseudo-selector as an alternative. 

In this particular case I had to go and add the headers to the code manually on a language I wasn't very familiar with, so I was wondering if there's an alternative to that.

Comment: No you can't. This is not possible with CSS especially as `content` cannot contain urls that are not images. Additionally pseudo-**elements** are meant for **styling** not adding *actual content.

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay. If that's the case, this could probably be posted as an answer? (I'm not 100% of how answering actually works here...) Since this answers to my bolded question of "Is it possible to do X".

Answer (score 0):

For the record, what you want is possible, but only in Firefox, using the `-moz-element` CSS function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element

```css
#baa::after {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  background: -moz-element(#boo) no-repeat;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="boo">Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="baa"></div>
```

Since this only works in Firefox, I can't really recommend it. Use other methods instead.